# Route and "e" flag

Tags: linux, routing, ipv6, route

```
k# route -6
Destination                    Next Hop        Flag   Met  Ref   Use  If
::/0                           fe80::8001      UGDAe  1024 0     0    eth0
[...]
```

What does flag "e" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It maps to `RTF_EXPIRES`. It means the route has a non-infinite lifetime. In this case, the kernel probably learned the route dynamically from a RA (Router Advertisement).

I recommend you use `ip` instead of `route` (and instead of `ifconfig`). Although it's Linux-specific and unportable, its syntax is much less archaic than the legacy commands. `ip -6 route` would even show you the actual amount of time before your route expires instead of just adding a `e` flag to say that it does.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on the meaning of `RTF_EXPIRES`.  Is there a source you used?

Comment: [ipv6: Fix problem with expired dst cache](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg190328.html) indeed suggests it's IPv6 RA.

Comment: @Mikel, I didn't find documentation as such for the meaning but there are multiple hits when grepping for it in `linux-2.6/net/ipv6` and the context around many of the hits makes the meaning quite clear, particularily `linux-2.6/net/ipv6/addrconf.c` line 1891 from a recent git checkout.

Answer (score 4):

The man page doesn't say...

But the `route` program comes from the [net-tools](http://net-tools.sourceforge.net/) package...

There's a git interface to the source [here](http://net-tools.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=net-tools/net-tools;a=blob;f=lib/inet_gr.c;h=332bf92c35d2d64ee44f0f7c1a932fdf7c0d6c5d;hb=796ba7f1e59883a85558996ea7785054ae45aac0#l146)

which gives us the following information:

```
 UP U
 GATEWAY G
 REJECT !
 HOST H
 REINSTATE R
 DYNAMIC D
 MODIFIED M
 DEFAULT d
 ALLONLINK a
 ADDRCONF c
 NONEXTHOP o
 EXPIRES e
 CACHE c
 FLOW f
 POLICY p
 LOCAL l
 MTU u
 WINDOW w
 IRTT i
 NOTCACHED n
```

So it means *expires*.